# Target final DIV of certain class for styling with CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a predetermined set of items generated by a different page which I can't modify. I want to style the first and last items in the list. The first item is no problem, but because the last item is not the last DIV in the list, I can't figure out how to modify it. Removing the last description DIV, which is also line 15 of this Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/CeJAS/ achieves what I want, but I can't modify the real HTML - the empty description DIVs are unfortunately part of the markup. Can this be achieved with CSS?

```
<div class="list">
    <div class="title">
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="description"> </div>

    <div class="title">
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="description"> </div>

    <div class="title">
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="description"> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing a bit of [Googling](http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/%3anth-last-child), I've found you can use `.list div:nth-last-child(2)`.

It's also supported by [IE 9 and so far 10](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t37).

Comment: Wow! Excellent. It's for a mobile site primarily accessed on iPhones so I think this will be perfect. Thank you!